# Django Formsets: Identifying the invalid form within a formset

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

I'm using formset to save my data but when one of the forms within  is invalid which means `my_model_formset.is_valid()` return `False` I can't know which one is Invalid. How can I find exactly which form is invalid so I return a precise error message to the user:

```
def my_model_detail(request, obj_id):
    MyModel = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=obj_id)
    MyFormset = formset_factory(MyForm)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_model_formset = MyFormset(request.POST)
        if my_model_formset.is_valid():
            # save the all the data in atomic transaction
            # send success notification
        else:
            # detect which form within the form set is invalid
            # send error notification
            return redirect(reverse('my-model-detail-view', kwargs={'obj_id': obj_id}))
```

In fact in addition I want also to be able to ignore invalid forms and save only the valid ones.

Comment: Each form in the formset will have it's own validation. If you're properly iterating over the forms in the formset, you should be able to see field-level errors with `form.field.errors`

Comment: Have you tried that, form.fields has no attribute 'errors'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the formset's errors with `formset.errors`. It's a list that contains the errors for each form in the formset.

If you want to process the forms individually, you can loop through the formset's forms. You can then treat each form as you would normally do, checking `form.is_valid()`, `form.errors`, `form.cleaned_data` and so on.

```
if formset.is_valid():
    print("Formset is valid")
else:
    # Formset is invalid, process forms individually
    for form in formset:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process form
        else:
            # do something with form.errors
```

Note that there may be errors that do not belong to a specific form. You can access these with `formset.non_form_errors()`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and specially for mentioning `formset.non_form_errors()`.